# Compare elements of 2 list and print only different one

Tags: python, xml

I have 2 xml files in this format:

```
<tag1>
<tag2>
<ID>integer</ID>
<randomtags>
<RESULT>a_long_string</B>
</randomtags>
</tag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
<tag2>
<ID>integer2</ID>
<randomtags>
<RESULT>a_long_string2</B>
</randomtags>
</tag2>
</tag1>
...
...
```

Now there are two files with the same format. I want to show IDs which have different result in both files.
My algorithm is like:

1. Get 1 ID from file 1, search it in file2. If match, then proceed to step 2 else go to next ID
2. Compare  tag for that ID in both files.

   (i) If same - don't print.

   (ii) If different - print.

I managed to get two list containing  and  tag only but now I'm not able to apply my algorithm in the right way.
My attempt:

```
import re
import sys
import os

for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)):

        #Regex to fetch IDs only
        idcmd="awk '/<ID>[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*/ {print}' %s | sed 's/<\/\?ID>//g'" % sys.argv[i]

        #Regex to fetch RESULT tag only
        resultcmd="awk '/<RESULT>.*/ {print}' %s" % sys.argv[i]


        id=os.popen(idcmd).read().split("\r\n")
        result=os.popen(resultcmd).read().split("\r\n")

        test=[[i,c] for i,c in zip(id,result)]
        print test
```

If any other way is there please explain. Thanks

Comment: Actually I did not know how to do that in python so I used 'awk' there. If any other solution is available please help.

Comment: Help ...Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the IDs from your file in python you should do something like this:

```
id_file1, id_file2 = [], []

filename1 = "tmp.txt"
filename2 = "tmp.txt"
```

Open File1 and get all the iDs

```
with open(filename1, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if '<ID>' in line:
            id_file1.append(line.strip()[4:-5]
```

Open File 2

```
with open(filename2, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if '<ID>' in line:
            id_file2.append(line.strip()[4:-5]
```

Compare the parsed Ids and print Found it when they are the same

```
for value in zip(id_file1, id_file2):
    if(value[0] == value[1]): print("Found it")
```